# typeAhead autocomplete is not working

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am new to typeahead. I am getting the `json` data from remote and is shown in the network. The problem is The returned data is not autocompleted in the text box. Below is my code

**Style and Script Used**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/handlebars.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/typeahead.bundle.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Textbox**

```
 <input type="text" name="language" placeholder="Language" id="typeahead_lang" class="tagsinput-typeahead"/>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
  queryTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,     
  remote: {
    url: '{{ route("admin.packagelanguage") }}',

  }
});

cities.initialize();

var elt = $('#typeahead_lang');
  elt.tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeaheadjs: {
      name: 'cities',
      displayKey: 'text',
      source: cities.ttAdapter()
    }
  });
});


</script>
```

**Json Returned data**

```
[{text: 'English', value:'1' },{text: 'Afar', value:'2' },{text: 'Abkhazian', value:'3' },{text: 'Afrikaans', value:'4' },{text: 'Amharic', value:'5' }]
```

I am using laravel framework. How to autocomplete the returned the data in that text box. Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but,this code works for me.

```
var elt = $('#elt');
 elt.tagsinput({

  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
  typeaheadjs: [{
     hint: true,
     highlight: true,
     minLength: 2
  },{
     name: 'cities',
     displayKey: 'text',
     source: cities.ttAdapter()
   }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanx for replay. i got the answer. My problem was returning json is wrong format.